# An error with asterisk in if statement

Tags: bash, shell, nawk

I'm having problem with the following code:

```
nawk -F "," '{if($2<=2)&&($9!=45)&&($11==2348*)) print $2}' abc12* | wc -l
```

The error is in `($11==2348*)`. I tried to put this number in variable `x` and do `($11==$x*)`.

Comment: what do you mean with the `$11==2348*`, numbers starting with 2348 or literal 2348* ?

Comment: You might need to provide some sample input, and tell us how your output differs from what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean a regex match change it to

```
$ awk -F, '$2<=2 && $9!=45 && $11~/^2348/ {c++; print $2} END{print c}' abc12*
```

note that you can incorporate line count in the script as well.

If you want equality check `$11=="2348*"` would do.  Will check that the field is literally `2348*` without any special meaning of `*`.

Comment: is  $11~/234*/  means equal ?

Comment: you have to check what special chars in regex mean. As written above it means the field starts with 2348.  I'm guessing that's your intention but can't be sure until you clarify.

Comment: yeas i mean that $11 starts with 2348 but 2348 have other numbers like  234812345 so i want to verify theat $11 be like that

Comment: i'm tring to make like that 
nawk -F "," '{if($2<=2)&&($9!=45)&&($11~/2348*/)) print $2}' abc12* | wc -l
but it doesn't work?!

Comment: `*` doesn't mean what you asked for. Please try my script as written.

Comment: It sounds from `$11 starts with 2348 but 2348 have other numbers like 234812345` like what the OP really wanted was `$11~/^2348[0-9]*/`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you intend to use regexp?

```
$11==2348*
```

should give you a syntax error as

```
2348*
```

is an incomplete multiplication.

For a regular expression match you would have to use

```
$11 ~ /2348*/
```

if you intend to have zero to man "8"s or

```
$11 ~ /2348.*/ or may be $11 ~ /2348[0-9]*/
```

if the intial intent is having any character or only digits after "2348"

Comment: i just need to make equal comparision, du u mean ~  the same as == ?

Comment: ~ is the "regexp" match operator. If you need equals then $11 == "2348*" is what you would need. (quotes around your literal.)

Answer (score 0):

i think your code would work just fine if you wouldnt have added one more ")" than expected. if you count them you have 7.... so this `($11==2348*))` should acctually be `($11==2348*)`